# XML SOAP XML format that maps to Map<String, String>

Tags: soap

Due to restraints to access to change of SOAP client, I have to change the output format of the SOAP produced by my API: I need to make the Java client, which uses Axes call.invoke and return Map<String, String>. How can I make the output below parsable Map<String, String>

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
   <promoteDemotePartResponse xmlns="http://DefaultNamespace">
     <promoteDemotePartReturn xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
      <item>
       <status>Success</status>
       <objectAction>checkin</objectAction>
      </item>
     </promoteDemotePartReturn>
   </promoteDemotePartResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What can I change in my xml output to make it work with unchangeable Java client.

I have access to change the format of the XML. I can only retrieve one value